# Ionic cordova app ios 4.4.0 splash screen then closes

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working with ionic，ionic serve and cordova run android both are working fine on the browser and on my android device properly. But cordova emulate ios starts the app shows the splash for like 2 seconds and then closes. I have tried updating my plugins. Then remove ios and cordova add platform ios@4.4.0 the latest version available. The problem is still there. Would be very helpful if someone can help me fivure out the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you are expecting?

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa thxx for your comment....I was expecting the app to work normal. like open app->splash screen -> then home screen. mines was opening->splash->then closes itself. it is working now after downgrading a few versions from the currently available one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it worked! with, if anyone else facing the same problem. The latest version @ios4.4.0 seems to be causing the error. try with this version:

```
ionic cordova platform add ios@4.1.0
```